# How can I securely transfer my data from on-prem HDFS to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a bunch of data in an on-prem HDFS installation. I want to move some of it to Google Cloud (Cloud Storage) but I have a few concerns:

- How do I actually move the data?
- I am worried about moving it over the public internet

What is the best way to move data securely from my HDFS store to Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 2):

To move Data from an on-premise Hadoop cluster to Google Cloud Storage, you should probably use the [Google Cloud Storage connector for Hadoop](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/tree/master/gcs). You can install the connector in any cluster by following the [install directions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/gcs/INSTALL.md). As a note, [Google Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc) clusters have the connector installed by default.

Once the connector is installed, you can use [DistCp](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current3/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html)  to move the data from your HDFS to Cloud Storage. This will transfer data over the (public) internet unless you have a special interlink setup with Google Cloud. To this end, you can use a [squid proxy](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/pci-dss#set_up_a_squid_proxy_server) and configure the Cloud Storage connector [to use it](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/issues/1).